# Accessing contents of a structure declared in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I have declared and defined a structure in example.hpp and example.cpp file. I want to use this structure in my main program. I have included the header file in my program. I tried to access one of the members of the structure in the main program. But it prints a garbage value. Is there a mistake in the way it is accessed?

in example.hpp

```
    class example
    {    
    struct Map
        {
            int a;     
            int b;       
            string c;       
        }object[];
    };
extern example::Map object[3]
```

in example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
example::Map object[] =                                                   
{
    {2,3,"xx"},
    {2,4,"yy"},
    {2,6,"zz"},
};
```

in main.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
example::Map object[3]
int main()
{
example::Map lut[3];   // array of objects to the structure
cout<<lut[0].a; // trying to access first row, first integer
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `object[];` is not a valid member array declaration - it doesn't have a size. And your `example::Map object[]` is a completely different object than the member of the class

Comment: I'm not even sure how you got this to compile, for me it throws multiple errors

Answer (score 1):

You have

- Defined a class in example.hpp
- Defined a global variable in example.cpp
- Defined a local variable in main

You aren't using the global variable in main at all.

---

Problems with the program:

- A non-static member variable may not be an array of unspecified length. The program is ill-formed.
- You didn't initialise `lut[0].a` so its value is indeterminate. You read an indeterminate value and as such the behaviour of the program is undefined.
- You're using `string` which you failed to declare.

Comment: Should I use 'object' in the main program?

Comment: @Divs If your intention is to use object in main, then perhaps I should. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the struct Map is private to the class example and so you should not be able to use that struct in your main function. I had to define the struct public and I had to add a size for the member object[] to get the code compiled.

The reason why your code prints only garbage values is because your local variable lut is not initialized.

Comment: How do I access the contents of the structure in the main program?

Comment: You mean how to access the contents of the global variable object being defined in example.cpp? You have to declare that variable by adding the line "extern example::Map object[3]" to example.hpp after the definition of the class or to main.cpp before the definition of the main function. After doing that you can use that variable in the main function.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but now it prints only zeroes.

Comment: You also added the line `example::Map object[3]` to main.cpp. With that you defined the global variable object twice, which should lead to a linker error when compiling and linking main.cpp and example.cpp. If you only compile main.cpp without example.cpp, then there is only the global variable object being defined in main.cpp, which is zero initialized. That may be the reason why the code prints zero. To get the code to print the values of the global variable object being defined in example.cpp, you have to remove `example::Map object[3]` from main.cpp